# Simplifying an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, function, output

I have the following Arrays which I need to define in PHP which I've done in a very basic way:

```
$ch1 = array("A-MTP-1-1","A-MTP-1-2","A-MTP-1-3","A-MTP-1-4"); 
$ch2 = array("A-MTP-1-5","A-MTP-1-6","A-MTP-1-7","A-MTP-1-8"); 
$ch3 = array("A-MTP-1-9","A-MTP-1-10","A-MTP-1-11","A-MTP-1-12");

$ch4 = array("A-MTP-2-1","A-MTP-2-2","A-MTP-2-3","A-MTP-2-4"); 
$ch5 = array("A-MTP-2-5","A-MTP-2-6","A-MTP-2-7","A-MTP-2-8"); 
$ch6 = array("A-MTP-2-9","A-MTP-2-10","A-MTP-2-11","A-MTP-2-12");

$ch7 = array("A-MTP-3-1","A-MTP-3-2","A-MTP-3-3","A-MTP-3-4"); 
$ch8 = array("A-MTP-3-5","A-MTP-3-6","A-MTP-3-7","A-MTP-3-8"); 
$ch9 = array("A-MTP-3-9","A-MTP-3-10","A-MTP-3-11","A-MTP-3-12");
```

But I was thinking there must be a simple way of writing this rather than writing out each one but not sure where to start, Would someone be able to point me in the right direction to simplifying this PHP as I will also be repeating it for the above but with B instead of A for each one.

Comment: Why don't you do the same thing using loop?

Comment: Use 2D arrays and loops.

Comment: Write it into text file... Use php to split it in way you want it to...

Comment: @Dikesh Can you point me in the direction of how I would do that please

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `range()` , `array_chunk` and `extract` to get this done

```
<?php

for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {           # Pass 3 as you need three sets
    foreach (range(1, 12) as $val) {    # 1,12 again as per your requirements
        $arr[] = "A-MTP-$i-" . $val;

    }
}
foreach (array_chunk($arr, 4) as $k => $arr1) {    # Loop the array chunks and set a key
    $finarray["ch" . ($k + 1)] = $arr1;
}
extract($finarray);   # Use the extract on that array so you can access each array separately
print_r($ch9);        # For printing the $ch9 as you requested.
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/131247)

**`OUTPUT :`** (Illustration for `$ch9` part alone)

```
Array
(
    [0] => A-MTP-3-9
    [1] => A-MTP-3-10
    [2] => A-MTP-3-11
    [3] => A-MTP-3-12
)
```

After doing that , you can use `array_chunk` to split the array to length of 4.

Comment: Simplest solution. but you could also change the loop to cover arrays with values `A-MTP-2-` and `A-MTP-3-`